# Adding 1 year to the sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a stored procedure to print the last day of month exactly next year

I am getting this years last date, but I want 30/8/2014

I already tried the following:

```
IF LAST_DAY( add_months( SYSDATE, 12 )-1)
```

But it didn't give me any output.

Comment: just as an aside, using a `SELECT...INTO` like this is just asking for a `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`. Put it in a cursor and fetch once.

Comment: @ninesided, not if `repid` is unique.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp agreed, it might not be a problem right now, but _we_ don't know for sure, and nobody knows how it could change down the track. I just wanted to highlight that this kind of code tends to lead to bugs and is best avoided if possible, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using -1? The following would work:

```
select last_day(add_months(sysdate, 12)) from dual
```

You might be getting no output if you're running this in SQL*Plus and printing is not enabled. Try:

```
set serveroutput on
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is 8/30/2014 use the following

```
select last_day(add_months(sysdate, 12))-1 from dual
```

If the requirement is last date of the month you can use Ben's Answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT add_months(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE),12) as NextYearDate from Dual
```

May this will help you.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16233)